# Good dictionary software

Tags: dictionaries

What is good dictionary software? I am asking about the ones that can be downloaded and used on Windows machines, and not online websites.

I thought Word Web is a good one, but are there any advanced and good dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Merriam Webster](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877798095) CD version. In addition to being a fine dictionary, it has a lot of tools for searching that help you find entries whose meanings contain certain words, it does anagrams, and so on. I like words, and this one feeds my addiction.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many software dictionaries. Microsoft Encarta, Webster, Babylon, but the best one among them is **Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English**.

It has a lot of different features which helps you to learn English, pronunciation in two languages, a lot of examples for words, phrasal verb search, a thesaurus which helps you to understand the differences among similar words, pronunciation of the examples, word Activator and so on. It defines words and expressions in a very clear literature. It has vocabulary trainer, resource for teachers, pop up dictionary, and writing assistant.

Of course it has two problems. First, it doesn't have a good synonym and antonym bank as Microsoft Encarta has. Second, it's not pronouncing words any position of the page.

But overall, I think it's the best dictionary available for English language learners.

Answer (score 0):

I use WordWeb software.  It's easy to use and free.  Also, you can try [wordnik.com](http://www.wordnik.com).